# How to validate string using RegExp in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am checking input string which can have only digits and optional single forward slash that should not be at start or end position.

```
123456789      // valid
3221345431     // valid
23243245/34    // valid
454556/322     // valid
45435//564     // invalid as more than one /
454354356/     // invalid as / is at end position
/454354354     // invalid as / is not start position
```

I tried using `RegExp` but its not giving me intended results.

```
> re = RegExp('\\d+\/?\\d+')
/\d+\/?\d+/
> re.test('12791771/21')
true                           // This is correct
> re.test('477199337932')
true                           // This is correct
> re.test('12200977/')
true                           // This is wrong because / is at end position
> re.test('122009//77')
true                           // This is wrong because more than one /
> re.test('/12200977')
true                           // This is wrong because / is at start position
```

What I am doing wrong so not getting `false` in last three cases?

Comment: `re = RegExp('^\\d+\\/?\\d+$')`

Comment: Adding anchors will do. If you plan to also match a string containing 1 digit, use `/^\d+(?:\/\d+)?$/`